# ExtJs treePanel

Tags: extjs

на `treePanel`  есть ветка 'Корзина' c `ID=11`. При нахождении внутри этой ветки должна появится кнопка 'Восстановить'. 
Как я могу узнать что нахожусь внутри этой ветки?

Answer (score 2):

Можно, например, создать переменную, которая будет регистрировать текущее положение. Регистрация может происходить благодаря слушателям событий в ветках.